# MVC Datasource: controller or model?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, activerecord, datamapper

Just a quick question: In an OOP MVC application, one key principle is the seperation of responsibilities. I therefor think that a model and the object that fetches the model from a database, file, xml, webservice, etc. should be seperated from the model itself. This can for example be done by implementing a datamapper.

**However, what do I do when I have a model that can be loaded from different sources? Should the model be in charge of the datasource, or is this the responsibility of the controller?**

An simple example could be a config class that can be loaded from a database or a file. Should the controller instruct the datasource, or should the model know when to load the config info from a database or a file?

Comment: Are you determining the data source based on a variable passed down from the view, basing it on operating environment, etc.?

Comment: @BryanNaegele: Not necessarily, but that could be possible. In the config example, I might be loading some global configuration data from a file, but load some more (user) specific data from the database. Other times the user will have influance on this dicision through the view and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have used frameworks were the datasource is informed by the controller MachII, Model-Glue (Coldfusion frameworks) and also from the model layer (ColdSpring) - like Spring in Java.

I think the key thing is to use what makes more sense to you, keep the coupling to a minimum and be consistent, meaning don't put datasource or object dependencies in multiple places.

You could also consider using a service type object to abstract the datasource and have it serve either who it likes.

That IOC file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans>

  <bean id="chartShareObj" class="model.charts.ChartShared" autowire="byType" />
  <bean id="trendChartObj" class="model.charts.TrendChart" autowire="byType" />

  <bean id="adminRightsDA0" class="org.datamentor.institution.RightsDAO">
    <constructor-arg name="dsn">
      <value>${dsn_dm}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="assessmentManager" class="model.assessment.Manager">
    <constructor-arg name="dsn">
      <value>${dsn_au}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

You can see the different datasources specified by  args via  args defined in a controller.

Comment: One of the problems I seem te encounter is that a model doesn't really know the context of the program. A controller is pretty much coupled with the current activity of the user, the model isn't. When I let the model choose, how can it know if it has to load data from a database of file (to continue on the earlier example).

Comment: @Thanton, that knowledge would be defined in the IOC (inversion of control) layer, like Spring.  That's how I have seen that handled. As you say, the model layer should be application agnostic, to promote reuse among apps.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answers. Like Bryan Naegele's answer, IOC doesn't fully seem to answer the question at hand. Things like a factory pattern, dependency injection and contexualized lookup still need to be implemented somewhere. Is there a best practice in applying these patterns in the model or controller?

Comment: Based on your last edit, is the following idea correct: the controller chooses the source, the model checks if the source exists and handles upon it?

Comment: implemented in a controller, at some level there will be coupling - this is pretty abstract and a common pattern.

Comment: controller specifies and IOC object *passes along to the model layer

Comment: Chosen as an answer. I am just pretty new to this site, can't give an upvote yet (need 15 reputation before I can do that).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your situation and response I would suggest looking into dependency injection.  You can then let it handle determining which data source to use based on whatever set of variables you want to let it determine things by.  This is what I use when I have multiple data sources and want to have the data source determined by some predetermined factors I have chosen.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

As to who should handle the injection, I leave that to a repository factory and simply ask for an interface in the controller.  The factory then determines based on the dependency injection which repository to provide.

Example:

Dependency Injection in an global Infrastructure class:

```
Bind<INewsArticleRepository>().ToMethod(context => NewsRepositoryFactory.Create((NewsRepositoryFactory.RepositoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(NewsRepositoryFactory.RepositoryType), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsArticleRepositoryProvider"])));
```

Repository Factory

```
public static INewsArticleRepository Create(RepositoryType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case RepositoryType.Mock:
                return new MockNewsArticlesRepository();
            case RepositoryType.Sql:
                return new SqlNewsArticleRepository();
            default:
                throw  new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Call in the controller for a repository

```
private INewsArticleRepository newsItemRepository;

public NewsController(INewsArticleRepository newsItemRepository)
{
    this.newsItemRepository = newsItemRepository;
}
```

Comment: Dependency injection looks like a part of the solution indeed. However, it doesn't seem to be the whole answer. The question about whethet the controller or the model should be in charge in this process, is still unanswered.

Comment: It does definitely, thanks! The controller has a controlling role (as its name implies) and gives the specifics to (for example) a repository. This is in turn used to manipulate the model.

Comment: Correct.  The controller just wants a repository, it doesn't care from where.  The factory just needs to be told which repository to provide and the dependency injection handles that.  There has to be coupling at some point but you're just trying to minimize it to a variable or configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

They way I do it in Coldbox is using CB's INJECT method in the model.  In the cfargument of the constructor, I specify:

```
<cfargument name="dsn" type="any" inject="coldbox:datasource:dsn">
```

And that's from specifying the dsn in the coldbox.cfc file, and calling it "dsn".  I keep it generic so I can copy this stuff to other projects and only have to change the DSN name in the coldbox.cfc.

But then after doing that, you get the dsn like this:

```
variables.dsn = arguments.dsn.getName();
```

I hope this helps, at least a little.

Rob